# Number(number).toLocaleString() adding long hyphen for negative numbers instead of minus sign

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(Number(-50).toLocaleString())
```

- Expected output: `"-50"`
- Actual output: `"−50"`

Why is `toLocaleString()` not using the regular minus sign and is there any way to change that?

Comment: Well what's your locale? US English gives me a hyphen character.

Comment: @Pointy The Slovenian locale `sl-SL` produces this.  `(-50).toLocaleString("sl-SL")`.  The OP's profile says they're from there.

Comment: And note that the name for the character you're getting is "Minus Sign".

Comment: @Pointy sorry, my locale is `sl-SL`

Comment: It's interesting that it does that but the answer to "why" might be difficult to find. Personally I prefer the minus sign over the hyphen for numbers because it looks better, but I can understand that it might be problematic.

Comment: @Pointy Basically it uses the hyphen because our native language spelling rules require using a hyphen. Did not know that, but since this has nothing to do with the method used I will close the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has nothing to do with code.